# How to zoom map fragment in seperate alert dialog on click

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-animation, android-alertdialog

In my application i am using 5 fragments, one fragment contains map. As per size limitation i cannot show all pin with zoom level 15 with marker.

[image: Initial Fragment]

So i want to display a bigger version of map fragment in side a alert box once use click on map fragment similar to this
[image: Required map fragment with zoom]

How i can achieve this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you worked with fragments before ? Also you dont need an alert box for that. This effect can be achieved with simple fragments.

Comment: @geekoraul No this is the first time i am using fragment. How can i achieve this effect with simple fragments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several approaches you can use.
1) use an activity with dialog theme 
2) jsut declare a floating FrameLayout inside your main layout and add a MapFragment to it.

Comment: Already solved problem yesterday anyways thanks for you ans :)

Comment: If you have solved the problem post your approach here. It will be helpful for others.

Comment: I used an activity with dialog theme android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen but it has one disadvantage map is not bright as it seems. Working on that will update the question once finds solution.